# The range in normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

We have normal distribution

$X = N(5 ,2)$

with 2 being standard deviation.

and we have to find a such as $P(  5 - a < X <= 5 + a ) = 0.99$

However how to proceed to find a? What is the right way to solve this? How to find "range" that has 99% chance that random variable X is in it? thanks for helping me.

Comment: You forgot the standard deviation..

Comment: the standard deviation is 2

Comment: Yes, I mean $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to say

Comment: You said you normalized it.... so for example, $\frac{5+a-5}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: i see my mistake i will edit Q

Comment: In R statistical software, where `pnorm` is a normal CDF and `pnorm` is a normal quantile function, `q=qnorm(c(.005, .995), 5, 2); q` returns (
-0.1516586, 10.1516586) and `diff(pnorm(q, 5, 2))` returns $0.99.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that,

$0.99=P(5-a< X\leq 5+a)=P(-\frac{a}{2}< Z\leq \frac{a}{2})$ and $Z\sim N(0,1)$

Now use the fact that the normal distribution is symmetric, hence all you need to do is find a value $y$ such that $\Phi(y)=0.995$ where $\Phi(y)$ is the distribution of a $N(0,1)$ random variable. After you have found $y$ simply put $y=\frac{a}{2}$ and solve for $a$

Comment: how did u get 0.995?

Comment: Use the symmetry of the distribution.... the right tail has to add the same probability as the left tail....so $\frac{1-0.99}{2}$